# What questions does "2001: A Space Odyssey" the book answer?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, arthur-c-clarke, 2001-a-space-odyssey

I love the film but still haven't read the book. They say it answers all the questions we ask while watching the film (and can't be answered without reading the book).

Comment: It could be also interesting to read Lost Worlds 2001. Short stories from the same author three of those are used for the latter movie and novel.

Comment: What questions did you have while watching the movie? Perhaps if you ask them, we who have read the book can answer them for you :). IIRC, there is nothing in the book that you can't _guess_ from watching the movie, but the movie doesn't make it as clear as the book does.

Comment: For more info on the ending, see this question: [What is the end of 2001: A Space Odyssey about?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/2579/143)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

AFAIK the book, which was written simultaneously with the screenplay, expands the description of the ending, which is where the vast majority of the questions come from.

The book explains what happened much better than the film, and gives more details.  It's also less likely to induce a seizure.

Comment: Agreed - I defy any rational adult that is not under the influence of any kind of mind-altering substance and has not read the book to watch the end of the movie (from the point where Bowman enters the Monolith) and give me a coherent explanation of what the blue blazes went on.

Comment: @TechParadox Does Pop-Corn count as a mind-altering substance?

Comment: @DavRob60: Depends on what you put on it.

Comment: it does, no matter what you put in it.

Comment: @Jeff well, the ending is the part that raises most of the questions. planning on reading it soon. googling for plot-answers is for losers.

Comment: I felt the same way about 2010.  The movie made almost no sense, if you had not read the book.

Comment: They wrote the book and the screenplay at the same time and went to different planets? How'd that happen?

Comment: The book "The Lost Worlds of 2001", also by A.C.C., delves into the making of the book, the movie, and the changes between the two. It's worth hunting down a copy if you're interested in the trivia of the making of both.

Comment: @Neth - Clarke originally sent the discovery to Saturn, but the SFX department couldn't give Kubrick a realistic looking Saturn so he opted for Jupiter instead. Clarke's sequels pretty much pretend that Kubrick's version is the correct one and ignore poor Saturn :)

Comment: @System Down one of the most interesting infos i got about the movie. Thanks! Clarke shouldnt have corrected it, gives the story a bit of a trashy feeling i like.

Comment: @System Down: It's not really true they couldn't give Kubrick a realistic Saturn.  It just couldn't be done within the budget and time allowed.  He did create a Saturn, but finished it after production.  (Doing Saturn meant doing Jupiter AND the rings, which was double the work.)  Douglas Trumbull (who did the FX for 2001) created a full Saturn for "Silent Running," a VERY low budget (less than $1 million) film a few years later.  Considering FX tech and how slowly it advanced in that era, such a low budget film would not have been able to to use new tech that wasn't around for 2001.

Comment: Keep in mind that "explains much better" != "IS much better". I liked the book's explanation when I was younger and needed answers to everything, but in growing older I prefer the ambiguity of the film. I think the two approaches reflect the mindset of Kubrick and Clarke, respectively.

Comment: It's been a while, and I don't have a source for it, but I recall reading the Clarke said that even he didn't know what Kubrick was doing at the end of the movie. As for Clarke's sequels, there were plot reasons for using Jupiter rather than Saturn, at least in *2010*.