# 2001: Confused benefit of monoliths to aliens

Tags: 2001-a-space-odyssey

I just saw 2001: A Space Odyssey for the 3rd time, but this time in 70mm — amazing. Anyway, I’ve been thinking a lot about the film and the role the monoliths played throughout it.

I understand that the question: “[What did the black monoliths do in 2001: A Space Odyssey?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104331/what-did-the-black-monoliths-do-in-2001-a-space-odyssey?rq=1)” contains the answer as to what the monoliths do but I don’t understand why the aliens placed these monoliths. How does it benefit them?

If you don’t know the actual answer (if there is one), I’d love to just hear what your belief is!

Comment: Hi mannyrothman welcome to SF stack exchange. You'll find your question has already been asked and answered here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104331/what-did-the-black-monoliths-do-in-2001-a-space-odyssey?rq=1 if you feel your question is different then please edit to explain what is different and I'm sure someone will answer.

Comment: Ah ok, updated my question, thanks!

Comment: Nice. Interesting, I'm not sure how much we know about the aliens but there are a fair few books in the series so this may have come up somewhere.

Comment: Ah I see. Also, how do I remove the “[duplicate]” tag in the title since I corrected my question?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/what-is-the-end-of-2001-a-space-odyssey-about This question seems to address your edits.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!